# Firefox Developer Edition, Responsive Design Mode window left aligned after last update

Tags: firefox

In the latest update of Firefox Developer Edition, the Responsive Design Mode window is aligned to the left; it used to be centered.

Is there any way to revert it back to the center, by custom CSS or whatnot?

I tried to dig through the Profile prefs under AppData and I couldn't locate anything.

What it used to look like:
[image]

What it looks like now:
[image]

(This is developer *edition*, not developer tools): https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/